# Image uploader with "Set Featured Image" link on front end

Tags: post-thumbnails, uploads, thickbox

I am loading `upload-media.php` file using `thickbox` on front end where user can upload images to the post.

**Question:** How to I trigger the `upload-media.php` so the link "set featured image" shows up on image manager, just like we see when we click on "set featured image" link on backend.

[image: Featured image]

**Here is the code for the thickbox:**

```
jQuery('.upload_media_button').live('click', function() {
            current_item = jQuery(this);
             container = "."+current_item.attr('rel');
             var request = url.media_upload+'?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true';
             //alert(request);
             tb_show('Image Manager', request);
             return false;
        });

        window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
             var img_tag = jQuery('img',html);
             //var attachment_id = jQuery('img',html).attr('class').replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
             current_item.siblings(container).prepend(img_tag).css("height: auto");
             tb_remove();
        }
```

I know I can take the attachment ID and set the featured image after form submission but that's the **Plan B** ;)

Comment: We already got jQuery 1.7.x - so please use `.on()` instead of `.live()`.

Comment: @Kaiser: Oh, Sure! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the `"Use as featured Image"` link you have to pass `post_id` to the `media-upload.php` file with the url so the request will be changed to:

```
var post_id = 234 // retrive the post id via php
var request = url.media_upload+'?post_id='+post_id+'type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true';
```

Make sure you add the `post_id` very first of the url. It didn't worked for me when i added the `post_id` to the last of the url.

**UPDATE:** Some javascript handling will be needed for the ajax response. Still working on to figure out that part. I will update my answer if i can figure it out.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to handle the ajax response?