# How to get future ID for post which haven't been created yet?

Tags: posts, uploads

**Calling Post ID:** Lets go first with calling post id definition :) This name i actually find inside a core file [`wp-admin/includes/media.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-admin/includes/media.php#L1167) which means for the post you requested the media upload. Media gets attached to the that post which the media uploader gets called.

**Question:** Well, for new post (when you click "add new post" or "add new cpt" and you open up `wp-admin/post-new.php` page. You will notice there is a post id already assigned to the possible new post. To check hover over the media upload button and notice the url.

[image: media upload]

So, **how to I find the `post_id` of the possible post?** I am trying to find out how to get that post id and searching through core file with no luck.

Appreciate your help :)

**Update:** Parhaps my question was little missleading. As i did not said where i am going to use the code. I am making a front end user dashboard where I need to get the id not backend admin panel, the image was for demonstration purpose. Going to use the code like on this question [Image uploader with "Set Featured Image" link on front end](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45124/image-uploader-with-set-featured-image-link-on-front-end/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the correct path on thinking about `post-edit.php`.

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-admin/post-new.php#L45

See how `get_default_post_to_edit` is called to return a new post. The second argument tells it to create a post in the database. The function is defined here:

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-admin/includes/post.php#L394

Note line 422: `$post_id = wp_insert_post( array( 'post_title' => __( 'Auto Draft' ), 'post_type' => $post_type, 'post_status' => 'auto-draft' ) );`

And where would WordPress be without hooks?

`do_action('wp_insert_post', $post_ID, $post);` can be seen in `wp_insert_post`'s definition here:

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/post.php#L2656

Thus, if you hook into is like so:

```
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'wpse_45419_hold_global_post_number', null, 2 );
function wpse_45419_hold_global_post_number( $post_id, $post ) {
    if ( $post->post_status != 'auto-draft' ) return; // not interested, thanks

    // do stuff with $post_id here...
}
```

This would be quite an interesting thing to have, of course, and is quite surefire. Alternatively, if you look at how the media button gets it:

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-admin/includes/media.php#L371

It uses `get_upload_iframe_src`, defined a little lower, which makes use of the global `$post_ID`, which brings us back to `post-new.php` where you can see it being defined on line 46:

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-admin/post-new.php#L46

So, generally speaking, any hooks that fire off after line 46 are all yours to hook into and tap the `$post_ID` global, including `wp_insert_post`, `media_buttons`, and dozens of others. Note that, `init` and `admin_init` come too early up the chain. And make sure the hook is specific enough to fire off only when you need it to. `wp_insert_post` is good, but will not have the global `post_ID` set yet, since it's going to be set just after the function returns.

Fascinating, isn't it?

Comment: Great! I just found the function `get_upload_iframe_src()` :) If save a autodraft when user opens a new post form on front end and use that post id. What do you think? But then I will need to know how to handle it (remove the auto draft) if user don't create a post (close that entry form)..

Comment: The auto-drafts are removed every 7 days http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-admin/includes/post.php#L418 as seen here, there is no need to worry about them, no?

Comment: If you're going to create a lot of data that you want to erase in case a post is removed look into [`wp_delete_post`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/post.php#L1948), note how any meta information will be automatically removed for the post as well; so you should have no fear of ID collisions, besides in 7 days the next post ID that is issued will probably be far away from the ones deleted and won't be reused.

Comment: Thanks! That works perfect!! :D Thanks for your time and so much details on your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

It comes down to a simple one liner:

```
var p_id = jQuery("#content-add_media").attr('href').split("post_id=")[1].split("&")[0];
```

and now `p_id` holds the post id.

**Update**
In that case you don't need the post id, just keep track of the attachment ids and once you create the post and get its id just update the `post_parent` field of the attachments to the newly created post idea, something like this

```
//array of attachment ids
$attachments = array(12,33,434);
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query(
    "
    UPDATE $wpdb->posts 
    SET post_parent = $post_id
    WHERE ID IN (".implode(",",$attachments) .")
    AND post_type = 'attachment'
    "
);
```

Comment: sorry, I was little misleading, updated my Q.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post looking for a way to get the next post id without creating a new post like when you are adding a new post/page which goes through post-new.php . Here's an example code I created for the next ID of a woocommerce post type `'shop_order'` but it does not create a new post/order. It's the same function as when you're adding a new page via post-new.php . This shortcode `[myget_default_order_page_to_edit]` will show the next ID number on the frontend. Past shortcode inside page. Paste the below code in your child theme functions.php or create it in code snippets plugin.

```
/**
 * Get the default page information to use.
 *
 * @since 2.5.0
 * @deprecated 3.5.0
 * @deprecated Use get_default_post_to_edit()
 *
 * Helpful examples: https://hotexamples.com/examples/-/-/get_default_post_to_edit/php-get_default_post_to_edit-   function-examples.html
 * https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_default_post_to_edit/
 * @return WP_Post Post object containing all the default post data as attributes
 * shop_order is a post type from Woocommerce. Replace shop_order with desired post type.
 * shortcode to view the next id/order # [myget_default_order_page_to_edit]
 */
add_shortcode('myget_default_order_page_to_edit','myget_default_order_page_to_edit');
function myget_default_page_to_edit( $post_type = 'shop_order'){
    
    require_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/post.php' );

     $order = get_default_post_to_edit($post_type, true);

     echo $order->ID;
     
// echo post id/ order id inside html
    echo "<div>The Next Order ID # {$order->ID}</div>";

}
```

Comment: Note that shortcode callbacks have to **return** a string. They must not use `echo` or `print`, because that would be printed directly when the post content is parsed for shortcodes, not when it's printed to the page.

Comment: I used this to develop a "add new" button linked to the permalink where the shortcode is located. I actually didn't know about not using `print`/ `echo` in a shortcode. The above code works for me but I could update it to change `echo` to `return`. I created a shortcode so that I could easily test and view it on the frontend. Since the author was using it for a Frontend Dashboard. If I make the changes would it be a better solution?

Comment: Thank you for letting me know by the way so I can improve my skills.